# R: join/merge of a table with two look-up tables based on a condition

Tags: r, join, merge, conditional-statements

I have a base dataset of people:

```
everyoneexample <- data.frame(
gender=c("Female", "Male", "Male", "Female"), age=c(18, 18, 20, 21))

> everyoneexample
  gender age
1 Female  18
2   Male  18
3   Male  20
4 Female  21
```

and two look-up tables:

```
scorefemale <- data.frame(age=c(18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23), 
  score=c(1.1, 3.3, 5.5, 7.7, 9.9, 11.1))

> scorefemale
  age score
1  18   1.1
2  19   3.3
3  20   5.5
4  21   7.7
5  22   9.9
6  23  11.1

scoremale <- data.frame(age=c(18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23), 
   score=c(2.2, 4.4, `6.6, 8.8, 10.1, 12.1))`

> scoremale
  age score
1  18   2.2
2  19   4.4
3  20   6.6
4  21   8.8
5  22  10.1
6  23  12.1
```

And I'm basically trying to get this:

```
    gender  age score
1   Female  18  1.1
2   Male    18  2.2
3   Male    20  6.6
4   Female  21  7.7
```

Everything I look up on conditional joins/merges assumes one main table and one reference table, but my problem calls for two reference tables.

Hopefully this example is clear, but please do fire away with any questions if you want me to clarify anything.

**UPDATE**: Thanks to Gregor, the most elegant answer seems to be just to make a temporary table out of an `rbind` of both reference tables, and then to do a left join using two "by" variables:

```
everyoneexample <- merge(scores_FandM, everyoneexample, by=c("age", "gender"))
```

Comment: Either (a) add a `gender` column to each of your look-up tables and use two left joins or (b) split your main table by gender and join each split to the appropriate lookup, then recombine. I would recommend (a).

Comment: Thanks for that Gregor, I tried this solution first as it seems clean and elegant, however I realised with attempting a second merge(), my dataset was making separate score.x and score.y columns, so I resorted to Nathan's solution.  I'm sure there's a simple parameter somewhere to fix that, but in lieu of trying to find it, Nathan's answer was already available... but thank you!

Comment: In the end, I did end up using your (a) solution.  To reconcile the multiple score columns formed after two joins, I had to do a df$score <- ifelse(is.na(df$score.x), df$score.y, df$score.x) just to amalgamate the columns, as my initial joins wouldn't place them into the same column.  Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: A slight adjustment that might save some fiddling would bebe to (1) add `gender` columns to each of your lookup tables, (2) `rbind` the lookup tables together, (3) join to the main data. This would mean you only need a single join.

Comment: Thank you Gregor, that is the most elegant answer.

Comment: Belinda-Jane, your update should be posted as an answer below, either by you or @Gregor if he wants. Also, please make it a complete answer (showing how scores_FandM is created, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Gregor, he suggests adding a *gender* column to each look-up table:

```
> scorefemale$gender <- "Female"
> scoremale$gender <- "Male"
```

Then combining the tables to form one large look-up table:

```
> scores_FandM <- rbind(scorefemale, scoremale)
```

And then finally left-joining the main table with the look-up table using two "by" variables -- *age* and *gender* -- effectively forming a *composite key* into the new, combined look-up table:

```
> everyoneexample <- 
      merge(everyoneexample, scores_FandM, by=c('age', 'gender'), all.x = TRUE)
```

Simple and elegant... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
female_rows <- which(everyoneexample$gender == 'Female')
female_matches <- merge(everyoneexample[female_rows, ], scorefemale, by = 'age')

male_rows <- which(everyoneexample$gender == 'Male')
male_matches <- merge(everyoneexample[male_rows, ], scoremale, by = 'age')

everyoneexample$score <- NA
everyoneexample[female_rows, 'score'] <- female_matches$score
everyoneexample[male_rows, 'score'] <- male_matches$score
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion on my real dataset one thing I didn't envisage was that my actual data table has age==NAs in it, and I had to add age==NA rows to my reference tables, but otherwise it all worked well.  Thank you!

Comment: Digging into the data, I've discovered that it's not actually correct.  After running just the Female portion, I ran a big dcast(everyoneexample, age~score, ...) on the main dataset and, whilst the nature of the look-up data has a unique score against each age, I'm seeing a distribution of every score against most ages.    (1/2)

Comment: (2/2)  Also, looking at the main dataset, each score appears in blocks, for example, the first score (age=15 in the Female look-up table) appears against the first four Female rows in everyoneexample, irrespective of age.  Then the next 100 or so Female rows in everyoneexample have the next score in the Female look up table (age=16), irrespective of the age in the everyoneexample table.